# How to run multiple jobs, one per GPU, with SLURM?

Tags: slurm

Apologies if this has be asked/answered before, but even after reading everything I can find, I am struggling to get SLURM to do what I want.

Let's say I have a machine with 4 GPUs. I want to train 4 models in parallel, each job running on a single GPU. I am using a job array and have a bash script like the one below. However, when I run this script,

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=train
#SBATCH --array=0-3
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --gpus-per-node=1

srun python train.py --config=$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID
```

the model is only using two GPUs at a time

```
            7824_1     gpu    train   vivekg  R       0:00      1 node
            7824_2     gpu    train   vivekg  R       0:00      1 node
        7824_[3-4]     gpu    train   vivekg PD       0:00      1 (Resources)
```

When I run `nvidia-smi`, I see only 2/4 GPUs on my machine are in use.

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.113.01             Driver Version: 535.113.01   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA RTX A6000               Off | 00000000:3B:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 30%   30C    P2             195W / 300W |  23856MiB / 49140MiB |     92%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA RTX A6000               Off | 00000000:5E:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 30%   27C    P2             179W / 300W |  42172MiB / 49140MiB |     98%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  NVIDIA RTX A6000               Off | 00000000:86:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 30%   18C    P8              20W / 300W |      3MiB / 49140MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  NVIDIA RTX A6000               Off | 00000000:AF:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 30%   17C    P8              20W / 300W |      3MiB / 49140MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A    637518      C   ...kg/miniforge3/envs/train/bin/python    23848MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A    637520      C   ...kg/miniforge3/envs/train/bin/python    42164MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Running `scontrol show job <JOBID> -d` doesn't show me anything out of the ordinary.

```
JobId=7825 ArrayJobId=7824 ArrayTaskId=1 JobName=train.sh
   UserId=vivekg(26289) GroupId=vivekg(26289) MCS_label=N/A
   Priority=1 Nice=0 Account=(null) QOS=(null)
   JobState=RUNNING Reason=None Dependency=(null)
   Requeue=0 Restarts=0 BatchFlag=1 Reboot=0 ExitCode=0:0
   DerivedExitCode=0:0
   RunTime=00:01:45 TimeLimit=UNLIMITED TimeMin=N/A
   SubmitTime=2023-10-27T13:48:36 EligibleTime=2023-10-27T13:48:37
   AccrueTime=2023-10-27T13:48:37
   StartTime=2023-10-27T13:48:37 EndTime=Unknown Deadline=N/A
   PreemptEligibleTime=2023-10-27T13:48:37 PreemptTime=None
   SuspendTime=None SecsPreSuspend=0 LastSchedEval=2023-10-27T13:48:37 Scheduler=Main
   Partition=A6000 AllocNode:Sid=basil:1508745
   ReqNodeList=chili ExcNodeList=sumac
   NodeList=chili
   BatchHost=chili
   NumNodes=1 NumCPUs=2 NumTasks=1 CPUs/Task=1 ReqB:S:C:T=0:0:*:*
   TRES=cpu=2,mem=90000M,node=1,billing=2
   Socks/Node=* NtasksPerN:B:S:C=0:0:*:* CoreSpec=*
   JOB_GRES=gpu:A6000:1
     Nodes=chili CPU_IDs=0-1 Mem=90000 GRES=gpu:A6000:1(IDX:0)
   MinCPUsNode=1 MinMemoryNode=90000M MinTmpDiskNode=0
   Features=(null) DelayBoot=00:00:00
   OverSubscribe=OK Contiguous=0 Licenses=(null) Network=(null)
   Power=
   TresPerNode=gres:gpu:1
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Could I see your slurm.conf file? I'm trying to implement something similar and it would help a lot

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what I was doing wrong. By default, SLRUM was allocating 90GB of memory per job. Each GPU only has 48GB, so one job was hogging two GPUs. Specifying `#SBATCH --mem` fixed the issue.